# How to navigate through form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer-8, element

I have written a webform with dynamically added form elements.
I create a number of fieldsets and then when some conditions are met,
I insert some select boxes in the fieldset I am interested in.

For example, I create the fieldset like :

```
document.write('<fieldset name="field__collection__">') ;
                                document.write('<legend align="right" style="color:#FF0066"><code>COLLECTION</code></legend><br />') ;
                                document.write('</fieldset') ;
```

Then, in order to access the fieldset and create a select box I do :

```
var html = form.elements["field__collection__"].innerHTML ;
                                for( netelement in CUSTOM)
                                {
                                        html = html + '<fieldset><legend align="left" style="color:#888888"><code>'+ netelement +'</code></legend>'
                                        var x = "__collection__" +'###'+ netelement +'###' ;
                                        html = html + '<select name=\"'+ x +'\" multiple="true" size="5" onsubmit="document.getElementById(\'MAIN\').submit()">' ;
                                        for( collection in CUSTOM[netelement] )
                                                if( collection != "icollection" )
                                                        html = html + '<option>'+collection+'</option>' ;
                                        html = html + '</select>' ;
                                        html = html + '</fieldset>' ;
                                }
                                form.elements["field__collection__"].innerHTML = html ;
```

The problem is that I can access the fieldset like : `form.elements["field__collection__"]`
and this works on Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome, it doesn't work on IE8 (and the problem is not the innerHTML).
More specifically, `form.elements["field__collection__"]` is undefined in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting your fieldset like this

```
var fieldSet = document.getElementsByName('field__collection__')[0];
```

And then elements in the fieldSet that have name of 'X' would be:

```
var nameOfxInFieldSet = fieldSet.getElemenetsByName('X')
```

Comment: Thank you Adam for your interest. What you have written works on Firefox, but this is not the case for IE. Do you have any ideas why this happens ?